# WebClient loses zone when fetching data from another service

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, webclient, zoneddatetime

I am trying to get data from another service. The database has fields like time stamp with zone.

```sql
creation_date TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL
```

In model `creationDate` is `ZonedDateTime`.

I store dates in `UTC+0` and want them to be up to date for any zone when requested.
In the service, I solved this problem by adding a zone to the mapper.

```java
.creationDate(notificationsHistory.getCreationDate().withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()))
```

When I try to get data using the `webClient` from this service, I get the dates again in `UTC+0`, although I get `UTC+3` (default time zone) directly from the service

In Service:

```json
"creationDate": "2022-04-23T13:19:49.361144 +03:00"
```

(time in `UTC+3`)

In WebClient query:

```json
"creationDate": "2022-04-23T10:19:49.361144Z"
```

(time in `UTC+0`)

Here is my request to service:

```java
    webClient.get()
      .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
        .path("...")
        .build(...))
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(Dto.class)
      .block();
```

Here is my WebClient configuration:

```java
  @Bean
  public WebClient webClient() {
    return WebClient.builder()
      .baseUrl(URI)
      .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
      .build();
  }
```

`creationDate` in model:

```java
 @Schema(
   description = "Date of creation"
 )
 private ZonedDateTime creationDate;
```

Apparently, I'm losing the zone already with `bodyToMono(Dto.class);`

Can I somehow configure the webClient to not lose the zone? It is very important that there is the right time from any zone.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244152/discussion-on-question-by-vladislav-sedov-webclient-loses-zone-when-fetching-dat).